# How to rotate edges on their own axis?

Tags: transforms

[image]

I'd like to know how to rotate all of the selected edges like the one that's shown below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Select all the edges you want to rotate.
2. Change pivot point to **Individual Origins**.
3. Change Transform Orientation to **Normal**

[image]

4. Press <kbd>R</kbd> button to rotate and <kbd>Z</kbd> button twice to rotate around the Z Normal axis of individual edges.